# Process a Perl qr RegEx string in reverse direction

Tags: regex, perl

I have a series of qr// RegEx string patterns to match URLs fed to my site. For example, `qr#^/safari/article/([0-9]+)\.html(\?(.*))?$#`. This string would match a path from a URL such as `/safari/article/299.html?parameter=1`. I have a separate subroutine where I can create URLs to link to different parts of the program. It occurred to me that it would be nice if that latter part could somehow use those aforementioned patterns I have already written -- it would reduce the likelihood of error if both the way URLs were generated and the way they are later processed came from the same set of patterns.

When a user comes to the site, my program takes the URL given to the server, runs it against strings like the one above and it will output `$1` and `$2` with the patterns it finds (e.g. "299" and "parameter=1," the two parameters for loading a page). In essence, now I'd like to do that in reverse and somehow provide `$1` and `$2` and feed them against that qr// string to create a new path output (say, I'd set `$1` to "300" and `$2` to "parameter=2," somehow merge that against the qr// string and get the output `/safari/article/300.html?parameter=2`.

Is there a simple way to do that sort of "reverse regex"? It seems like one way to do it would simply be to do a regex pattern match against those two parenthetical patterns, but that somehow feels sloppy to me. Is there a cleaner way?

**EDIT:** Part of the reason for storing the patterns in RegEx is that they all get thrown into a multidimensional array for later processing that can help figure out what module should be called. Here's a couple of sample items:

```
 [
      { function => 'article', pattern => qr#^/safari/article/([0-9]+)\.html(\?(.*))?$#, weight => 106 },
      { function => 'topCommentedPosts', pattern => qr#^/safari/top\.html$#, weight => 100 }

 ]
```

Comment: Maybe a good way to put this is that it is like the gameshow *Jeopardy!* If I have the answers and I have the regex, can I get back to the "question"? Or put another way, "42"...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you want to achieve. The following works, but going this ways seems rather fragile and dangerous. Why do you need to generate the paths, anyway?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $TEMPLATE = '/safari/article/$1.html?$2';

sub generate {
    my (@replacements) = @_;
    return $TEMPLATE =~ s/\$([12])/$replacements[$1-1]/gr
}

sub match {
    my ($string) = @_;
    my $regex = "$TEMPLATE";
    $regex =~ s/([?.])/\\$1/g;
    $regex =~ s/\$[0-9]+/(.*)/g;
    return $string =~ /$regex/
}

use Test::More;

is generate(300, 'parameter=2'), '/safari/article/300.html?parameter=2';

is_deeply [match('/safari/article/299.html?parameter=1')], [299, 'parameter=1'];

done_testing();
```

Comment: Thanks, @choroba. Basically, my goal is to be able to change the way different functions in the program are requested since this program is used on multiple different sites. For example, maybe I want all the articles "/safari/" and with ".html" endings on one site and "/foobar/" with ".arbitrary" extensions on another. The set of regex pattern matching strings works to make that easy customizable for the input side. However, when pages are output, those too need to use the customizable formats for linking to other resources on the same site in the canonical way.

Comment: I wonder if I could take your concept but leave the template as the whole RegEx string rather than replacing $1 and $2 in the matching function? Right now I have a whole list of these patterns that call different modules all placed into an array. I'll add the format of that array in my original question.